# How do I fsck_apfs an encrypted volume?

Tags: disk-utility, fsck, apfs

I'm playing with macOS 10.13 beta but a volume seems to have been corrupted during migration to APFS. I can boot and log in but soon get a "static screen". I launched recovery mode and launched disk utility. When trying to run First Aid I get exit code 65. So I started the terminal:

If I run `diskutil apfs list` I see the volume encrypted and locked.

I then tried `diskutil apfs unlockVolume /dev/disk1s1` which unlocks AND mounts the volume.

Now `fsck_apfs /dev/rdisk1s1` and `fsck_apfs /dev/disk1s1` give `error: container /dev/rdisk1 is mounted with write access.`

How can I try and repair this volume? I suspect that something happened during the initial migrate and the volume is stuck in half APFS, half HFS+ somehow.

Update:

If I go back to "Disk Utility" and unmount the volume there and return to Terminal, then `fsck_apfs /dev/disk1s1` gives `error: container /dev/rdisk1 is mounted.` I try and unmount the "Image Volume", but `diskutil umount /Volumes/Image\ Volume/` gives `Volume Recovery on disk1s3 failed to unmount: dissented by PID 0 (kernel)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to change the format of the command given in the [other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/294497/37797). The correct command is:

```
diskutil apfs unlockVolume /dev/disk1 -nomount
```

Answer (score 3):

Apple got back to my via Bug Reporter, saying `diskutil apfs unlockVolume -nomount /dev/disk1` should unlock the volume but not mount it. This worked for me, but unfortunately I still can't run `fsck_apfs` without it crashing.